# Using commas in mathematical formulas

Tags: math-mode, spacing, punctuation

I need write some formula, but I don't know how to arrange the comma's place.

```
$p,\ q\in N$, blabla $0<a,\ b<1$ blabla $i,\ j=1,\ 2,\ \dots,\ n$
```

or

```
$p,\;q\in N$, blabla $0<a,\;b<1$ blabla $i,\;j=1,\;2,\;\dots,\;n$
```

or

```
$p$, $q\in N$, blabla $0<a$, $b<1$ blabla $i$, $j=1$, 2$, $\dots$, $n$
```

or

```
$p$,~q\in N$, blabla $0<a$,~$b<1$ blabla $i$,~$j=1$,~$2$,~$\dots$,~$n$
```

which one is more acceptable?

Comment: You will get better answers for such math questions on our sister site http://math.stackexchange.com. They use LaTeX for their formulars too, so there should be no issue showing them code.

Comment: `$0<a$, $b<1$` and `$0<a,b<1$` usually mean two different things! Do you mean two separate conditions or one and the same condition for `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt The mean is "a and b are both in (0,1)".

Comment: @needhelp: Then you shouldn't use any additional space after the comma.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are some subtleties in this kind of sentences.

You have to decide whether the space in something like "p and q belong to N" you want a normal space after the comma or not and then be coherent across the document. So you can do either

```
$p$,~$q\in N$
```

or

```
$p,q\in N$
```

In the first form the tie is necessary, or you may get

> *p*,`<line break>`*q* ∈ *N*

which is unacceptable. I prefer, for this case, the second form that makes clearer that the two variables are treated in the same fashion. In this case we can consider that the comma belongs to the formula, being just a shorthand: `$p,q\in N$` actually stands for the longer and clumsy `$p\in N$ and $q\in N$`.

To the contrary, some conditions applying to one or more variables should better go in different formulas; therefore

```
$0<a,\ b<1$
```

should be considered wrong because (as shown in the comments below, which refer to the previous version of this answer) it is ambiguous: does it mean that *a* is greater than zero and *b* is less than one or that both should be between zero and one? So separate them:

```
$0<a<1$, $0<b<1$
```

should be preferred if both variables vary between zero and one. One might use

```
$a,b \in (0,1)$
```

which seems, however, a bit too technical.

Something similar applies to ranges, but the commas in the range aren't part of the formula, so

```
$i,j=1$, $2$,~\dots, $n$
```

is, in my opinion, the preferred way to go. For the first bit the choice made for the above case should be respected, of course. One might also do

```
$i,j=1$,~$2$,~\dots, $n$
```

so as to ensure that no line break is taken after the 1. In difficult line breaking cases, that tie can be removed. There's no problem with a line break after the dots, because a range is expected. An input such as

```
$i,j=1,2,\dots,n$
```

results in too crowded an output (and poses line breaking problems).

A hint: whenever you feel the necessity to use `\␣` (control space) or `\;` in a formula, ask yourself whether it's better to do *separate* formulas.

Comment: The advice to use `$a>0$, $b<1$` is not sound since the OP means `$a,b\in(0,1)$`. In this case one can use `$0<a,b<1$`, but this is also somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @HendrikVogt This actually *proves* that `$0<a,b<1$` is ambiguous, no matter what amount of space is used after the comma. I'd prefer `$0<a<1$ and $0<b<1$`, which is longer but surely unambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

This is subjective, but I would say neither. This is what I'd do:

```
$p,q\in N$, blabla $0<a$, $b<1$ blabla $i,j=1,2,\dotsc,n$
```

Comment: Me too, since LaTeX adds a small gap after the `,` in math mode by default, which seems to be enough in my eyes

Answer (score 2):

It is actually recommended in the TeXbook by Knuth that you split "list" formulas across commas.  Thus, he suggests you write

```
$a$, $b$, or $z \in S$
```

rather than

```
$a, b$, or $z \in S$
```

*specifically* because it allows line breaks, whereas math formulas never break after commas for fear of breaking an "argument list" `$f(a,b,\dots,z)$`.  He also recommends a tie after one of those commas but I can't remember which (according to Hendrik Vogt's comment it's actually after the "or"); if ties are important to you then you probably know which one you want.

Regardless, you should *not* do

```
$p,\ q\in N$, blabla $0<a,\ b<1$ blabla $i,\ j=1,\ 2,\ \dots,\ n$
```

or

```
$p,\;q\in N$, blabla $0<a,\;b<1$ blabla $i,\;j=1,\;2,\;\dots,\;n$
```

because explicitly playing with spaces is almost never right.  If you don't like the math mode spaces as separators, then that's a clue you shouldn't use math mode for this kind of textual construct.  (That's different from the issue of writing an integral as `$\int f(x) \, dx$`, which you *should* do, though arguably you should use `\mathop{dx}` or some other macro that inserts the space automatically.)

Comment: Can you tell _where_ in the TeXbook Knuth says this? The closest I could find is the recommendation to write `for $x = a$, $b$, or~$c$` and not `for $x = a, b$, or $c$`. I'd _not_ recommend writing `$a$, $b$, \dots, $z \in S$`!

Comment: @Hendrik As I didn't have the book in my lap as I wrote that, it's possible that I was recalling this passage.  It certainly sounds familiar.  I will edit the answer, as anyway the "or" case is more closely related to the text of the actual question.

Comment: My point is the `\in`, which I wouldn't use like this. It would be OK with a textual "in".

Comment: @Hendrik On p.173, he advocates writing `$i = 1$,~2, $\ldots\,$,~$n$` rather than `$i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$` (the thin space is part of an example on spacing in formulas).  It's not exactly the same, but I think it's functionally identical.

Comment: You're right, this is quite close. And I can't explain why I can accept it rather with `=` than with `\in`.

Comment: @Hendrik Thinking more about it, I don't know if I think Knuth is right about this at all.  He does do some "optimizing" things that trade off semantic value for some form of processing efficiency.  For example, writing `2` instead of `$2$` (he says as much in his [tugboat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf)).  So I think breaking lists out of math mode rather than using, say, `\allowbreak` as one would use `~` is another such questionable practice.

Comment: Knuth even advocates `$\{\,p\mid p$~and $p+2$ are prime$\,\}$`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the third version

```
$p$, $q\in N$, blabla $0<a$, $b<1$ blabla $i$, $j=1$, 2$, $\dots$, $n$
```

you have the biggest chance that TeX will properly break your document into lines. Putting unbreakable material between dollars may be a cause of overfull or underfull boxes, looking ugly.